# How to fix cb_console_runner.exe failed on CodeBlocks?

Tags: codeblocks

I could not run any program in CodeBlocks. When I  click to run button, then log tab display this message. I was trying to fix this problem by reinstall codeblocks but It doesn't work. Also search google but can't find any solution.

```
Executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe "D:\Timus\test.exe" (in D:\Timus)
Execution of 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe "D:\Timus\test.exe"' in 'D:\Timus' failed.
```

Here is my small program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just found a solution from CodeBlocks Forum.

The default install directory for Code Blocks was, C:/Program Files (x86)/codeblocks, which MingW installer did not like due to the 'white spaces' in Program Files (x86).

So reinstall the full codeblocks in different directory with no spaces in its name e.g. C:/codeblocks from C:/Program Files (x86)

And it's now work and my problem is solved.

Comment: This is NOT the answer.  Codeblocks runs fine in the default location.  You must have changed something else.